# Preload de Pdf com Javascriipt ou Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Possuo um input do tipo file e preciso gerar um preload mostrando parcialmente o conteudo do pdf. Possuo o seguinte código

```html
 <label for="">Selecione o arquivo de orçamento</label>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" class="form-control form-control-sm" onchange="verifyMimes(this)" required>
     <img id ="Tela" Name ="Tela"/>
```

Segue o script

```js
  function verifyMimes($input) {
        let allowed = ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'pdf', 'PDF'];
        let fileExtension = $input.value.split('.').pop();
        if (typeof allowed.find(function (ext) { return fileExtension == ext; }) == 'undefined') {
            $('#alert-pdf').text('O arquivo de diagnóstico deve possuir o formato jpg, png, jpeg ou pdf')
            $('#pdf-send').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {

            $('#pdf-send').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#alert-pdf').text('')

            if ($input.files && $input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#Tela').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }
                console.log($input.files[0])
                reader.readAsDataURL($input.files[0]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Ele exibe se o arquivo for um jpg, png ou jpeg, porem queria realizar o preload de um pdf. Alguém sabe como seria possivel realizar esse procedimento?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa criar uma condição para quando for um arquivo PDF, ele utilizar a tag ***iframe***,
segue o método como eu faria:

```
function preloadFile($input) {

        const screen = $('#preLoad');
        if ($input.files.length <= 0)
            return;

        const { type } = $input.files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            if (type != 'application/pdf')
                screen.html(`<img src="${e.target.result}"/>`)
            else
                screen.html(`<iframe src="${e.target.result}"/>`)
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL($input.files[0]);
    }
```

O HTML ficaria assim:

```
<label for="">Selecione o arquivo de orçamento</label>
<input type="file" name="files" class="form-control form-control-sm" 
onchange="preloadFile(this)" required>
<div id="preLoad"></div>
```

Aconselho criar a verificação de mimes em outro método e chama-lo no método ***preloadFiles***

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente sem nenhum erro. Obrigado.