# Preview PDF javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, upload

Tenho um sistema que faz upload de arquivos e imagem, com o FileReader do js consegui renderizar a imagem de acordo com o evento change do input file.
Minha dúvida é a seguinte:
É possível pré visualizar arquivos de texto como .pdf, .docx, .text e etc...?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/418991/preload-de-pdf-com-javascriipt-ou-jquery/418999#418999

Comment: Obrigado, esse tópico me ajudou